# "Prove that the 'set of all sets' does not exist", could you check my proof and tell me if it's okay?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> "Prove that the 'set of all sets' does not exist"

So, I'm going through "Introduction to set theory" by Karel Hrbacek, and Thomas Jech. The book proposes proving that the set of all sets doesn't exist. So here's what I came up with.

**$V$ is a set $∧$ $B$ is a set $⇒$ $¬∃V,∀B [ B∈V ]$**

Suppose $∃V,∀B [ B∈V ]$, then the Axiom Schema of Comprehension can be used

[image]

So $∀V,∃!T [ x∈T ⇔ x∈V ∧ x∉x]$ and $T$$=${$x∈V|x∉x$}. Now, if $∀B [ B∈V ]$
then $T∈V$; If $T∈T$ then $T∉T$, and if $T∉T$, $T∈T$.

So I have

$T∉T ⇔ T∈T$.

A contradiction.

$∴¬∃V,∀B [ B∈V ]$

So, **Is the proof ok?**

Comment: Your proof is rigth but you must to change the cuantifiers, is "$\exists! T\forall x[x\in T...]$".

Comment: While @Godel seems to comprehend (based on the above comment), I am quite confused.  You start out "Suppose there exists $V$ such that for all sets $B$, $B$ is in $V$." This suggests we have a particular $V$ in hand.  Then your next sentence is "So for all $V$..." (and now I am lost as I thought there was only one particular $V$ were considering..I also do not quite follow the sentence that follows). It may also help to point out what your $P(x)$ property is that you are using.

Comment: @Michael the cuantifiers are wrong. Is $x$ instead  of $V$.

Comment: @Gödel : Thanks!  can you also tell me the difference between "$∃!V$" and "$¬∃V$"?  I'm not familiar with the symbols, but I woudl expect both to mean "there does not exist a $V$"

Comment: @Michael both are in regular use.  $\exists !V$ means that there exists a unique $V$ such that yada yada, while $\neg \exists V$ means that there does not exist a $V$ such that yada yada.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Thanks!  So I was interpreting ! wrong.  I now observe the axiom schema of comprehension says "there exists a B" not "there exists a [unique] B" and so I  am a bit confused with how Daniel's first line introduces "[unique] T." I gather that $P(x) = x \notin x$.

Comment: @Michael this is possible by extensionality axiom.

Comment: Oh.  I think I will give up trying to understand the argument given in the question, as there seems to be too much unstated for me to follow.

Comment: @Michael don't worrie, you can change the "$\exists!$" cuantifier by the "$\exists$" cuantifier and the proof is rigth too.